# What constitutes a "context" in Pose mode?

Tags: armature

I have an armature associated with a mesh. In Pose Mode I have oriented the armature the way I want, so I press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire armature and then I press <kbd>`I`</kbd> to insert keyframes.  I've done this successfully on simple models while following tutorials, but back in my real model I'm getting the following error and I don't understand what context is being looked for.

> No suitable context info for active keying set

What constitutes a "context" in Pose mode?  What should I be looking for in my model structure that is leading to such an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [keying sets documentation](http://aligorith.blogspot.fr/2010/12/animating-in-25-getting-to-grips-with.html):

> ### No suitable context info for Keying Set
>
> This error occurs when either:
>
> 1. The Keying Set requires that some specific type of data is selected (i.e. all builtin Keying Sets require that you have some selected object/bone)
> 2. When using the "Available" builtin Keying Set, and the object that you're trying to keyframe doesn't already have any keyframes/F-Curves, this error will be shown as it there are no existing keyframes/F-Curve on the selected object(s) to insert keyframes on

The keying set can be selected/cleared using the [image: keying set controls] in the header of the Timeline window.

Comment: Thank you, @Aldrik, that looks to be a very thorough write-up.  I did use Internet search tools to try and find that error message, but none were found.  And I looked in the Blender wiki before turning to Blender.SE -- but I'm glad I did!!