# two bones, one I can add a keyframe, the other I receive this message "no suitable context info for active keying set", how to fix it?

Tags: animation

I compared everything inside blender about any kind of properties and nothing special differed between the two bones named "whatever" "DEFwhatever2".

I exported to the highly readable xml collada dae format to compare both with meld, and I saw nothing special, and even after I re-imported both bones from the .dae, one of them were still not keyframable.

all these does not solve the problem:
["No suitable context info for active keying set"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219202/no-suitable-context-info-for-active-keying-set)
[Why do I get an "no suitable context info for active keying action" message when trying to keyframe a camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170649/why-do-i-get-an-no-suitable-context-info-for-active-keying-action-message-when)
[What constitutes a "context" in Pose mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/what-constitutes-a-context-in-pose-mode)

This question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned ones, sorry if you disagree.

Comment: Please include a blend file where this problem happens. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: just prefix any bone with DEF to replicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

The only different thing was the name.
The problematic begins with "DEF".
The moment I put a letter "a" before it like "aDEF", it started accepting keyframing!

here has some info about naming:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49081/9567
but there is no tip about how breaking is the DEF prefix!

I cant find any official documentation about these prefixes and how they may interfere in your workflow, so I guess we must be prepared for more surprises?

Comment: "MCH" prefix gives no error message and blocks keyframing too. To help changing many, create a mouse/keyboard macro to click and rename where you are pointing at.

Comment: Are you sure this is not related to Keying Sets? When the bone has no keyframes and you set the active keying set to *Available* then exactly this error occurs. The DEF and MCH are common prefixes and don't matter. It's a common naming convention. Blender only cares about suffixes like *Left", ".L", "_L" for mirroring.

Comment: If the only thing was the name, and you weren't using the Whole Character Acting keying set, then you've encountered a bug and should file a bug report.  There is no code in Blender that uses prefixes to prevent keys being added, except [Whole Character Keying set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html#whole-character-keying-set) and the list of prefixes it ignores is listed in the manual: (“COR”, “DEF”, “GEO”, “MCH”, “ORG”, “VIS”) + the error message you get only happens if a keying set is active.

Comment: yeah, that is it, I always use wcks, as I think it is easier to work that way