# Where can be found official and updated docs about how prefixes and other naming conventions may add or block blender functionalities?

Tags: documentation

This took me many hours to finally really guess the problem: [two bones, one I can add a keyframe, the other I receive this message "no suitable context info for active keying set", how to fix it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239594/two-bones-one-i-can-add-a-keyframe-the-other-i-receive-this-message-no-suitab/239595#239595).

Now I want to avoid being surprised, mostly because the error message does not specify why it is happening.
If it could have said "you cant add a keyframe because of the DEF prefix", I would have spend 1s solving the problem. :(

So, is there any updated documentation about how these namings behave? in a direct consideration of blocking and/or adding functionality.

PS.: I cant add this tag "naming-convention" but I guess it is essential now.

Comment: The manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html#whole-character-keying-set

Comment: perfect thx! google was not helping... anyway, I would have had to know it before facing the problem, as the error message does not help.

Comment: Strange, link posted is top match after googling "blender keying sets"

Comment: yes of course, but the name of the bones was the last thing I thought that could cause that problem... I mean, this doesnt dismiss this difficulty to new users, and may make them give up on using blender...  I wasnt looking for naming conventions, I was looking for bones behaving differently and the non helpful error message....

Comment: Do note that this limitation only applies if you are using the Whole Character Keying Set.  Otherwise the bone name prefix is irrelevant to whether or not the bone can be keyed.

Comment: mm... that must be it, I always use wcks, as I think it is easier to work that way